# Jquery easyticker script not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

We have recently been working on a dashboard for on of our web applications. The Dashboard mainly uses ASP.NET SignalR so that information can change in real time without browser refreshes.

One of the requirement is to have a faceebook style news ticker which shows an overview of a message board. I recently came across a jQuery plugin called Easy ticker. Basically it shows elements within a div every now and then.

Initially the div content is empty and is injected one the information becomes available, this is done via SignalR. But whenever I reference the easy ticker plugin nothing is showing up. I used firebug so see the output and everything seems to be okay is there anything I'm doing wrong? Thank you

```
 <html>

<body>
<div id="latest-messages">

   <div class="message-content" style="position: absolute; margin: 0px; top:      51.911805555555546px;">
   </div>

</div>


<script src="js/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.easy-ticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.signalR-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      $('#latest-messages').easyTicker({

            direction: 'down',
            interval: 7000          

      });

      // Declare a proxy to reference the hub
      var hub = $.connection.messageHub;

      // Create a function the hub can call to send messages
      hub.client.receiveMessage = function (message) {

      // Html encode the message
      var encodedMessage = $('<div />').text(message).html();

      var data = JSON.parse(encodedMessage);

      // Clear previous messages
      $('.message-content').empty();

       // Display each item
       // in the json-array
       $.each(data, function () {

           $('.message-content').append(
              '<div>' +
              '<b>' + this['Subject'] + '</b>' + '<br/>'
              + 'Date Created: ' + this['DateCreated'] + '<br/>'
              + 'Sent by: ' + this['SentBy'] + '</div>'

              );

           });


        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may not be related to the problem but include jquery.js before adding anyother js file

Comment: @dakait doesn't seem to make any difference still not seeing anything. In terms of output I'm expecting something like [this](http://www.aakashweb.com/resources/pages/demos/jquery-easy-ticker/)

Answer (score 0):

The data sent from SignalR to your receiveMessage client method is likely not `stringified` but instead a normal JavaScript object. Try `stringify`ing it before HTML encoding:

```
  hub.client.receiveMessage = function (message) {

      // Html encode the message
      var stringifiedMessage = JSON.stringify(message);
      var encodedMessage = $('<div />').text(stringifiedMessage).html();
      // ...
```

Comment: the message is serialized from a collection using Newtonsoft.Json so I'm able to get a JSON object and its data with no problem but the news ticker plugin is the one which does not show anything

Comment: FWIW, SignalR serializes hub parameters using Newtonsoft.Json for you, so no need to do it yourself.

Comment: okay...so what your saying is that I can just pass the collection and SignalR will serialize for me? thats pretty interesting. However my problem is still the fact that the jQuery easy ticker is not showing anything even after the results come through okay